# Change file associations (not default applications) in Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: mate, file-association, caja

I have a shell script that for some reason Ubuntu Mate decided is an audio file. I know how to set the default application to open files of that type, and I have it set to my editor.

However, I would like to know how to change the type Caja recognizes the file as having. For example, under properties the type is listed as "Amiga SoundTracker audio (audio/x-mod)". I would like that changed to "plain text document (text/plain)" or something along those lines.

This would allow me to not set the default application for all files of the audio type as a text editor, and it would get rid of an annoying play icon when the mouse goes over the file icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing ProjectLibre on Ubuntu 16.04. The default file association for `mpp` files was Videos. The immediate solution was to use the Nautilus file explorer, right click on an `mpp` file, select Properties, then use the Open With tab to choose ProjectLibre as the default application for opening this file type.

But even after doing that, the system still showed `mpp` files as being Videos. To remove the `mpp` extension from that mime type, I had to edit the mime database:

1. in terminal, go to `/usr/share/mime`
2. `grep <i>extension</i> *`
3. the above command will show you which `xml` file(s) includes the extension in a mime type
4. edit the `xml` file with `sudo` and your editor of choice, search for the extension, and remove that line which will look like

   - `<glob pattern="*.mpp"/>`
5. you can then add that pattern to another mime type if you want to... in my case for `mpp` files, I removed the `mpp` pattern from the Videos type listed in `freedesktop.org.xml`, and added it to the `application/x-projectlibre` type listed in `projectlibre.xml`
6. `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`